# Configuring Mercurial hg merge tool for Mac

Tags: macos, merge, mercurial

I am on a Mac (Yosemite 10.10.5) and have been using `git` since forever. I am now working on a legacy project that is stored in Mercurial (`hg`) and although it *kinda sorta feels similar* to `git`, there are some definite differences that I'm trying to understand/get used to.

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to merge locally. I cloned a project, did some work to it on `default`, and am now ready to push it to the remote repo. However, several other developers have also made **conflicting** changes to source files in that repo in the meantime. So I now need to merge (and manually resolve conflicts) before I push.

What "`hg` diff tools" are available for Macs? How do I configure `hg` to use them when `hg merge` detects conflict? Also, **very importantly**, can someone confirm that `hg merge` will *always* resolve non-conflicting differences for you?

Comment: So, what's the question? Of course there's merge. And of course it works. And then there are different merge tools which also work, each doing different things in case of conflicts (and defining 'conflict' slightly differently). Depends on which you want. Read the wiki: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration Use what you want. This question as-is is definitely is 'too broad' as-is or 'opinion-based'.

Comment: Thanks @planetmaker (+1) - that is the link that is giving me confusion! Its only example is "`mymergetool.something = something`", but how do I know what the valid values for "`something`" are? For instance, I would image that defining "`mymergetool.something = mindblown`" would not then go ahead and use [Atom](https://atom.io) for resolving merge conflicts, etc. **The question here is: what are the valid values for "`something`"?** If the thoughtless response is "*Anything that can act as a merge tool for `hg` brah*", then my followup question is "*Well the what are valid `hg` merge tools?*"

Comment: This is a valid, scoped configuration question.

Comment: At least 50% is "google merge tools for me" ;) - you can basically use any you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want. You can probably configure most merge tools to work with mercurial. The internal tools are not that bad, but a 3rd-party one might be more what you like, thus you should choose the one you are most comfortable with.

The actual configuration depends on the tool; personally I'm very comfortable with kdiff3: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KDiff3

But there's many others, often you find the required configuration when searching for the tool name and mercurial.
Some random finds:

- http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/index.html
- http://meldmerge.org/
- [Use WinMerge as TortoiseHG Merge tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073543/use-winmerge-as-tortoisehg-merge-tool)
- http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_versioncontrol.asp
- ...

See also the list of merge-related pages on the mercurial wiki: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KDiff3?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=merge&titlesearch=Titel - it contains configuration for many tools.

The general way on how to configure it is described in the merge tools section https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration (also see `hg help merge-tools`.